# SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]'FIELD' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql-server, laravel, odbc

I am using Laravel: 5.7 , MS-SQL: 2012.

Going to make a custom Order By before run ->get() from MS SQL

My code is below:

```
  $MonthOrder = implode(',', ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']);
  $listData->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(t2.Month, $MonthOrder) DESC"))
```

I get this error :

**SQL:**

```
select * from [dbo].[EXT_Data_DESC_Gamingdatas] as [t2] 

inner join (

select MAX(id) AS id, [Year], [Month], MAX(updated_at

) AS updated_at 

from [EXT_Data_DESC_Gamingdatas] group by [Year], [Month]

) 

max_table on [max_table].[id] = [t2].[id] and [max_table].[updated_at] = [t2].[updated_at] 

order by [t2].[Year] desc, FIELD(t2.Month, Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec) DESC)
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]'FIELD' is not a recognized built-in function name

.

How can I solve this problem? I can't find any proper ans...

Answer (score 1):

`field` is a MySQL function. SQL Server doesn't have it.

You can use a `CASE` expression instead.

```
...
CASE
  WHEN t2.month = 'Jan' THEN
    1
  WHEN t2.month = 'Feb' THEN
    2
  ...
END
...
```

Or change the schema and store the data using different types. If possible a date/time type or at least some numeric type for the months.

Comment: Thanks for your comment...
I find the way to do it...
I will try do it later on...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sticky
I solved the custom order by Adding a case when and order by this column

```
                DB::raw("(
                    CASE 
                    WHEN (Month = 'Jan') THEN 1
                    WHEN (Month = 'Feb') THEN 2
                    WHEN (Month = 'Mar') THEN 3
                    WHEN (Month = 'Apr') THEN 4
                    WHEN (Month = 'May') THEN 5
                    WHEN (Month = 'Jun') THEN 6
                    WHEN (Month = 'Jul') THEN 7
                    WHEN (Month = 'Aug') THEN 8
                    WHEN (Month = 'Sep') THEN 9
                    WHEN (Month = 'Oct') THEN 10
                    WHEN (Month = 'Nov') THEN 11
                    WHEN (Month = 'Dec') THEN 12 
                    END
                ) as MonthOrder"),
```